# NullPointerException while generating signed apk in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm not able to generate signed apk in android studio. Its throwing error like - **Information:Gradle tasks [:avakaash:assembleRelease]
Error:java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
Information:BUILD FAILED**.

Its working fine **when debug and run appication** on device and emulator. So I'm not able to generate signed apk. 
my project gradle looks like -

```
           apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.inbridge.avakaash"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

 dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':library')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile project(':payUMoneysdk')
compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.9.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and main gradle look like-

```
     buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}


allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
      mavenCentral()

  }
  }
```

error screen shot
[image]

and gradle console report-
[image]
please help me to solve this error, thank you in advance.

Comment: show your full logcat . clean and rebuild . you can use `buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'`

Comment: Exception is clearly mentioned. Click on Sync Now wait till its complete then build.

Comment: you can see more details in Gradle console

Comment: I rebuild so many times also its throwing error

Comment: in Gradle console its only showing that check "messages" view

Comment: I rebuild so many times also its showing error while generating signed apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same problem i did following changes and it solved my problem hopefully it will help for you. Compare gradle with yours.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inbridge.avakaash"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    dexOptions {
        dexInProcess = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')

    /* 4) Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */

    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.7'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.4.8'
    compile 'life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
}
```